# how to get env variable in scss

Tags: laravel, sass, environment-variables

I want to get one env variable data in my scss file by using mix in Laravel. How to get that?

I have used something like this. But this one is a URL, so, it is not getting.

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main-v2.scss', 'public/css', {
    data: `awsUrl: "${(process.env.MIX_AWS_S3_CDN)}" ;`
})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it. Follow steps as below,

Correct me if wrong, you want to pass an URL to `main-v2.scss` file as a variable.

1. Add a variable in your `.env` file as below,

   `MIX_AWS_URL='https://your-aws-endpoint.xyz?v1'`
2. In your `webpack.mix.js` file, add as below,

   ```js
       mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main-v2.scss', 'public/css', {
          // Use "data" for prependData instead of data.
          data: '$awsUrl:\'' + process.env.MIX_AWS_URL + '\';'
          // single quotes needs to be added as your URL contains : (colon) so, it may create an issue. Better to escape.
       })
   ```
3. Next, you can directly use `$awsUrl` variable in your `main-v2.scss` file as below.

   ```
       // Pass to function
       @import url($awsUrl);

      // Or assign to another variable
      $myVariable : $awsUrl;
   ```

That's it!

---

#### Update

For Laravel 8+, use below in step 2,

```js
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main-v2.scss', 'public/css', {
   prependData: '$awsUrl:\'' + process.env.MIX_AWS_URL + '\';'
   // single quotes needs to be added as your URL contains : (colon) so, it may create an issue. Better to escape.
})
```

Comment: I'm trying it on laravel 8 but an error shown

Answer (score 2):

I only got it working requiring `dotenv` myself inside `webpack.mix.js`.

This should work:

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('dotenv').config();

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main-v2.scss', 'public/css', {
    data: '$awsUrl:\'' + process.env.MIX_AWS_URL + '\';'
})
```

Comment: Yes. Importing the dotenv package is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

for those who are using **laravel 8+** the parameter `data` changed to `prependData`

```
  mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main-v2.scss', 'public/css', {
       prependData: "$awsUrl:'" + process.env.MIX_AWS_URL + "';"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not working on Laravel 9

In webpack.mix.js file

```
.sass('resources/assets/css/theme.scss', 'public/css/themes/style.css', {
    additionalData: '$awsUrl: ' + process.env.MIX_ASSET_URL + ';'
})
```

In scss file

```
@import url($awsUrl);
$assetUrl: $awsUrl;
```

Comment: you have to escape the URL components like ```:``` and ```/``` etc by quoting in single colon.
```'$awsUrl: \'' + process.env.MIX_ASSET_URL + '\';'``` just like that