# How to pass .env variables to .scss file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, environment-variables

I'm interested if there is a way to send var from .env file (I'm using custom webpack, reactJS, dotenv, and sass-loader) to .scss file. What I'm trying to do is to send path (string) to my scss to change font url.

On my localhost url is /fonts/font.ttf, but my app is deployed to the subfolder on the server, so it should be something like /shop/fonts/font.ttf.

Tnx in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Have a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111930/how-to-get-env-variable-in-scss or this https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1778

Comment: Much appreciated. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `additionalData` property from sass-loader options

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              additionalData: '$env: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ';',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

More info and another approach here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#additionaldata

Comment: I did that, including it in my styles as a string was a problem. Cheers