# Use different boostrap _variables files on different .env variables Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, variables, bootstrap-4, import, sass

Is there a way to use different bootstrap variables by using custom _variables file, selected upon some .env variable of Laravel 8?

something like, in app.scss:

if APP_VARIABLE = 1, then @import custom1_variables.scss

if APP_VARIABLE = 2, then @import custom2_variables.scss

and so on...

Would only want to select different _variables file, not the main app.scss file, which would be the same for all versions, but using its own _variables file.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Gert B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2911020/gert-b) suggestion, doing what [how to get env variable in scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111930/how-to-get-env-variable-in-scss) describes, I have had no success.

1. Add my variables in .env file,

```
MIX_VARIABLES='variables1.scss'
```

2. In my webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css',
{prependData: 'custom_variables:\'resources/sass/'+process.env.MIX_VARIABLES+'\''}).version()
```

3. Next, I have used my 'custom_variables' in my app.scss:

```
@import 'custom_variables';
```

But then I get an error of

> Can't find stylesheet to import.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get env variable in scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111930/how-to-get-env-variable-in-scss)

Comment: I am not sure. At first glance I have hardly understood the answer you refer. Let me deeply see it later and see whether you are right or not. Thank you!